# Jackson JSON: only consume a single object from stream

Tags: java, json, jackson, inputstream

I'm trying to get Jackson to read a single object from an input stream, and then stop reading. It looks like the default behavior is to read the entire stream and discard any extraneous data, as demonstrated by this code sample:

```
    byte[] data = "{\"hello\": 1} abc".getBytes();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    new ObjectMapper().readTree(is);

    System.out.println(String.format("-> %s", new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(is))));
```

which outputs `->`.

Is there a way to ask Jackson to only consume data from the InputStream until it's read a full JSON value? Or, alternatively, to have it fail if there is any extraneous data at then end of the file?

I've looked at [JsonParser.Feature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.Feature.html), but I don't see anything that applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS) to produce a `JsonParseException` if any trailing tokens are found. You just have to enable it in your `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS);
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(input);
```

This will produce the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'abc': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (String)"{"value": "test"} abc"; line: 1, column: 43]
```

By the way it doesn't matter if you pass a `String` or an `InputStream` or anything else.

Comment: How do you access the JSON object that was read in this case?